# broadCastReceivers Vs CallBackListeners

Tags: android, callback, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager

After I worked with the `BroadCastreceivers` of the Networks, a question occured to my mind, since the `broadCastReceivers` almost work as if they listen to any system changes and notify the user about these changes, only if, the user has registered to listen to these system change events using `RegisterReceiver()`. The question is

What is the difference then between `broadCastReceiver` used in `Connectivity Manager` and the `CallbackListeners` used in `LocationManager`, or in other words, why the `LocationManager` does not use `broadCastReceiver and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CallbackListener`  will be used, when you’re code initiates an asynchronous call and awaits an answer to it.

`broadCastReceiver` will be used, when something can happen unexpectedly and at anytime